# Callback function in Slate Material Editor

Tags: maxscript, 3ds

Is there any callback function available, which is triggered while we attach a texture map to a material using the slate material editor.

Reason:
I have a custom material and if the user don't have a valid license I don't want him to attach any texture to the custom material. In the Compact material editor I achieved this by disabling the UI to create map. But when I am using the Slate material editor I can connect a texture to my material.

So my idea is if I get a call back function from slate material editor when I tries to attach a map, I can perform a licence check and stop him from creating the connection. Am I doing it right or do you guys have any alternate suggestions.

Thanks,
Saneesh

Answer (score 0):

The maxscript manual has lot's of information about it here:

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-7C91D285-5683-4606-9F7C-B8D3A7CA508B.htm

Scroll down to topic named:

```
Node Material Callbacks:
```

and there you have the following:

```
materialOtherEvent:
```

The supplied function will be called whenever the node's material has been changed.

Try and use that to catch your event, and apply the result you need based on your license status.

Comment: Thanks Stig. These events are node related right? What if my material is not assigned to any nodes? Thanks for the link. I will work my way out from this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing a continuous callback on your scene (ie, on events that are triggered with normal scene interaction).  Its does cost in terms of performance, provides no additional security, and you'd be surprised the number of issues that this can cause with other system components. There is definitely a downside to interrupting another components operation and changing the expected outcome.  If another part of max is setting the texture, and doesn't check that the operation is failed, you could potentially end up with crashes.

One suggestion would be to move your validation to OnSave.

Pre-save, check for license.  If no license found, set your textures to 'undefined' (with an appropriate warning message of course).  This means you aren't constantly thunking in and out of maxscript with every user action related to materials, you have a single point of entry to maintain, and best of all, it lets the user try out your plugin if it has no license.  It does have the downside that a scene shared from a licensed user to an unlicensed one cannot be resaved by the unlicensed user, but your options are somewhat limited unless you go to C++.

However, I wouldn't put too much time or belief into security based in maxscript.  MxS is by nature editable by users, even without source code it wouldn't take someone long to find your security and disable it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the concern of security in max script, but currently I have no option to use C++. About the call back functions I am not looking for events that are triggered on normal scene interaction. I looking for events that are triggered on assigning textures to a material. Also I will check the event only when Slate editor is opened. I think this can remove the risk of crash.